# Importing CSV's with different Column Headers each time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

First of all, Thanks to StackOverFlow community for helping me to learn ruby on rails. As part of learning I'm working in a project, which basically accepts different csv/excel files into app, process it and export.

For eg., If a csv column headers is like `name, email, phone`

next csv column headers will be contact `name, address, email, country`

Code to import a csv:

```
rows = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")

      rows.each do |row|
       //Processing each rows.

      end
```

My queries,

Since the each file have different column headers, how can i import into database?

Is it okay to import csv files in runtime without saving in db to process and export? This does not sounds natural to me. Pls guide me the right path.

Comment: Could you please provide your code snippets, like how you are doing import, so that I can provide suggestions to incorporate dynamic headers.

Comment: You could map every CSV record to an Hash `entry` and use `ActiveRecord::Base.create()` with the `entry` hash as argument. See [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

Comment: @Dusht Csv import is straight forward please check now.

Comment: @sschmeck if the csv file is bigger in size, do u think still hashing is good idea?

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula How big do you mean?

Comment: @sschmeck Thanks for your input, let's say more than 10K records. Saving all records into database as Mohamed suggested below makes more sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table for importing csv data to. Let's call it `CsvDatum`. Fix columns that are shared by all your csv's and create a third `text` column to store a hash containing the extra attributes. Let's say all csv's have name and email. You schema should be as follows.

```
  create_table "csv_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",         limit: 255
    t.string   "email",        limit: 255
    t.text     "extra_columns",  limit: 65535
  end
```

In your model

```
class CsvDatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :extra_columns, Hash
end
```

Now when you are reading your csv file create an instance of the `CsvDatum` class to hold row data.

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  data = CsvDatum.new(name: row["name"], email: row["email"])
  row.delete["name"]
  row.delete["email"]
  data.extra_columns = row.to_hash
  data.save
end
```

Comment: Fascinating, how you approached this problem. Thanks a lot, exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
def your_method
    allowed_attributes = [ "arr1", "arr2"] # list all possible attributes here
    data = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
    header = data.row(1)
    results = []
    (2..data.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, data.row(i)].transpose]
        data_row = Your_model.new
        data_row.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k } #it maps the header with data
        results << data_row
      end
    end
    return results # final data
  end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you input, much appreciated.